# loadUrl android - кириллические домены

Tags: android

Подскажите, как можно подключить кириллические (пуникод тоже не работает)  домены для webview или придется создавать второй домен ?

Comment: Что значит `не работает`? Какие ошибки вы получили?

Comment: ну просто не открывается, белый экран ) Латинница-то работает, а вот с кириллицей или пуникодом проблемы